# So I built a new rig and put ubuntu 14 64bit on it as only Os, i have 2 xfx radeon 6870 cards in

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, graphics, radeon, xbmc

one is dual dis and the other is not I have the Cd for the non dual dis but I have no idea how to install the drivers, im sooo noob to ubuntu but i rly like it...

I want to dual boot windows also just because I am way more familiar with it but I have no idea first off howto install the graphic card drivers and I do not have any idea how to partition the 240 ssd to even begin to put any of my win os's on....I guess first question is the amd drivers fopr my graphic cards and then how to partition the drive to install a windows boot.....also if you dont mind i have a usb drive with xbuntu kubuntu and xbmc for ubuntu which id also LOVE to have on my rig in ubuntu....would ne of them be handy to have on and why? My ultimate goal with the rig is to run several monitors for work and some play. I will not be gaming nething that will need the cards to much. mainly for the multiple display.

Answer (score 0):

Install windows first to its own partition then once windows has drivers and updates then boot ubuntu and install that secondly. Ubuntu will walk you thru its dual boot setup easily at that point. There are other ways but this is by far the most straightforward since your new to ubuntu.
Keep in mind how many total partitions you will want before you start windows setup. so you can divide a single HDD capacity by that number during windows setup to leave enough room for the other 3 operating systems later.

Btw I recommend SSD over HDD always if you have some budget left in your build and you dont need a ton of space 250GB SSD will not dissapoint per dollar.

Comment: I have a 240 Kingston Ssd that I am loading my OS and some programs on,this ssd will be strictly Windows, Ubuntu, and the few small programs I run. I also have a 4 terabyte WD My Book that I have my media stored in as well as a few 2Tb WD blacks and a few 320 WD blues. These of course for now will be where I am storing the bulk of my movies, music, and pictures. My problem at this time with the install of windows is the uninstall of Ubuntu first. I tried to erase it on secondary drive of another pc and ended up in grub rescue.